# htaccess rewrite rule for similar domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a whole host of domains that need to point at one server, and they all have a similar domain where just the city changes on each one.

Each city is in a separate folder on the server, so for example /newyork will be "shoppinginnewyork.com" and /california "shoppingincalifornia.com"

Is there a way that I can set up a regex rule for any future domain so that it will automatically pick up the city and redirect or rewrite to the new domain? They will all start with "shoppingin"..

Thanks

Comment: is all domain pointed to same directory or different directory?

Comment: every site is in a different directory, i.e. /sites/newyork and /sites/california

Comment: You can try use regexp in rewrite for example this like this `shoppingin(.*)\.com` in rewrite cond and use this input `$1` if I don't wrong for next cond check exist dirrectory, after you can use this `$1` in rewrite rule for updating request.

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-setup-semiautomatic-per-folder-wildcard-subdomains-on-your-local-linux-based-development-computer/ check this link maybe this help resolve you answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wildcard in your VirtualHost's ServerAlias directive:

Have a look on below apache `virtualHost` configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerAlias shoppingin*.com

  DocumentRoot "/sites"

  # Then rewrite subdomains into different directories
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shoppingin(.*).com$
  # Use the %1 captured from the HTTP_HOST
  # For example shoppinginnewyork.com writes to /sites/newyork
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "/sites/%1/$1" [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Tested it on local machin for two domains.

Comment: @Martin there is %1 and $1  - %1 will match the (*) of http host while $1 will rewrite the url to particular folder...

Comment: haha, sorry , looking at it again my eyes previously saw two percentage signs, rather than a percetage and a dollar. Thanks for the info though :)